# how to get the access_hash from channel_id in telegram with Tlsharp and c#?

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I have a program developed by [Tlsharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) and I want joining channel that I have its **channel_id**, but for joining channels I need **channel_id** and **access_hash** for `TLRequestJoinChannel` request.

So I need to get **access_hash** from **channel_id**.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you find any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

this code works 100% :-)

```
var channelInfo = (await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLResolvedPeer>(
new TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLRequestResolveUsername
{
    username = "ChannelID"
}).ConfigureAwait(false)).chats.lists[0] as TeleSharp.TL.TLChannel;

var Request = new TeleSharp.TL.Channels.TLRequestJoinChannel()
{
    channel = new TLInputChannel
    {
        channel_id = channelInfo.id,
        access_hash = (long) channelInfo.access_hash
    }
};

try
{
    var Respons = await client.SendRequestAsync<Boolean>(Request);
}
catch (exception ex)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: your code works with channel's userName, but i just have channel_id. you know i want to join channels that their message forwarded to specific channel. and in this situation i just have integer variable that it is channel_id. thanks for your answer. :-/

Answer (score -1):

```
   var dialogs = (TLDialogs) await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();

        var channel = dialogs.chats.lists
            .OfType<TLChannel>()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.title == "channelName");

             long access_hash = (long) channel.access_hash;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Hi Amirhossein and thanks for your answer but as i describe in question I just have a channel_id and i don't have channel Name  
by the way it would be helpful if you describe what is  chatsingle in your code ???